# Не могу подключится к БД

Tags: php, mysql

После переустановки ОС не могу подключится к БД, код не менял, раньше работал без проблем, ОС linux mint.

```
    class SqlDriver
{
    private static $instance;
    private static $connection;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance == null)
        {
            self::$instance = new SqlDriver();
            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db_name');
            if (!self::$connection)
            {
                die ('Connect error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            echo ' Creatе connection!<br>';
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

ошибки не выводит, просто белый экран.

Comment: Так может стоит начать с включения отображения ошибок? error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не было расширения mysqlnd

Чтобы установить:
sudo apt-get install mysqlnd

Перезагрузить апач:
service apache2 restart